# Extracting images from Google images

Tags: mysql, database, import.io

I'm making database with movies and I don't know how to save images from Google images and sort them with certain movie. 
In database I have 17000 movies and I crawl them from IMDB with import.io but images are too small.
 Some advice, please?

Comment: 1) What is it you're looking for?
2) What have you tried already?

Comment: @MichaelWiggins I'am looking for images on web for my movie database

Comment: You misunderstand, are you wanting the application to crawl IMDB for example and get the movie covers and send them to the database, or something else?

Comment: @MichaelWiggins no I want to crawl images but no from IMDB but from google images and then to sort them with movies (if it's possible)

Comment: It doesn't sound feasible in my experience, mainly because google image results don't always result in a file name of "myFavFilm.png", so it would be difficult to single this out.

Comment: @MichaelWiggins so what is the best solution becouse imdb images are too small

Comment: I'd suggest you get the images manually, then add these to their respective database rows

Comment: @MichaelWiggins all 17 000 movies images manually?
It's too many

Comment: Fair point, quick question, is this intended to go into production or is it a self-set project?

Comment: @MichaelWiggins it's a self-set project

Comment: Then you my friend have set yourself a seriously over-complicated task, and I wish you well. My personal stance on this is that, admirable it is, the task has already been done by IMDB themselves =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [advanced image search](http://www.google.co.uk/advanced_image_search) functionality in google images:

You can use that to get the images you want manually, or if you want to automate this with import.io you can append one of the following parameters to a url in a query:

- `&tbs=isz:l` - large images
- `&tbs=isz:m` - medium images
- `&tbs=isz:lt,islt:xga` - images larger than 1024x768

(there are more parameters you can set, this is not a complete list)